# EmberJS: Updating property inside object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Little and strange issue.
I have an array of objects. Here is my controller.

```
AmbiantBox.AmbiantsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myArray: [],
  fillData: function(){
    //loop
      this.myArray.push({index: 0, status: 'hide'})
    //loopEnd
  },
  updateState: function(idx){
    arr=this.get('myArray');
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;++i){
    obj=arr[i]
    if(obj.index==idx){
      console.log(idx);
      obj.set('status','show');
      console.log('===========');
   }}}
});
```

I call this updateStats function from viewSide.
It works fine till the line where i console the parameter idx but code seems to break where i set the object. There are no errors in console as well.

Strange. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery?

Comment: @Vega: Calling this updateState function via jquery. And the other purpose was to attract more people to answer. Being Honest.

Comment: @PalashMondal: Already tried. Here is the error.  
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Ember's `set` and `get`'s it's probably a good idea to use `Ember.Object` and `Ember.Array` as well.

Try this:

```
AmbiantBox.AmbiantsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  myArray: Em.A(),
  fillData: function(){
      obj = Ember.Object.create({index: 0, status: 'hide'});
      this.myArray.pushObject(obj);
  },
});
```